# Resume activity closing the top ones on stack

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose to have 3 activities: A, B, C.
I launch A than B than C. How can I resume activity A (NOT create it again) closing B and C?

**EDIT**:

Start B from A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Android calls onPause and onStop for A.

Start C from B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Resume A from C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Android calls onDestroy(), onCreate() and onResume() for A.

Answer (score 1):

Use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag for starting intent.

```
Intent intent_to_a=new Intent(C.this,A.class);
                intent_to_home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent_to_a);
```

Your activity A will be resumed only if it is not destroyed manually using finish(); or by the OS itself.

From [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Comment: Thank you @David. That code actually does what you said. The problem is when I launch the intent for resume A, android calls onDestroy() on A first, and then it creates a new instance of A. I never call finish() on A. You know why?

Comment: @DanieleVitali Sometimes OS does so when it requires some RAM.

Comment: combining Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP it works. Thank you anyway

Comment: @DanieleVitali thanks for sharing knowledge :) kudos.

Comment: This answer is wrong. If you use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` this will clear all activities from the stack **including the current instance of the activity you want to launch**. It will then create a new instance of the activity you want to launch.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution by myself.

Combining Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP Android does not destroy activity A.